# Field formatter migration: How do I setup the related yml files?

Tags: 9, migrations

I've custom formatters in Drupal 7. In Drupal 9 I've a custom module to provide the same formatters. How do I have to setup the migration yml-File, if the names of the formatters in D7 are the same as in D9. Unfortunately the documentation isn't that helpful.